# Using LINQ To Interleave Two Lists

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

So here is what I'm attempting to do:

```
symbolList: 1,1,1,2,2,2
valueList:  a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2
result:     1|a1|b1|c1,2|a2|b2|c2
```

The a,b,c for each symbol are all different values
For each symbol there will be the same amount of corresponding values. So for symbol 1, there are three values that I would like joined with it. For symbol 2 I want the second set of three values joined to it, etc. 
However, with my current implementation, I currently get:

```
result:     1|a1|b1|c1|a2|b2|c2, 2|a1|b1|c1|a2|b2|c2
```

Here's my current code:

```
List<string> results = symbolList.Distinct().Select(f => 
String.Join("|", new List<string>() { f }.Concat(valueList))).ToList();

string value = string.Join(",", results);
```

I've attempted to use group by in some fashion, but haven't found a viable result doing that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you use the zip function to produce pairs (1,a), (1,b), (1,c), (2,a)... and then use group by to collect the pairs by the first item?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do here.  The code below from Habib gives you the result that you want if you are trying to match all distinct items from the first list with all distinct items from the second list.  If you are trying to do something else, you'll have to explain better what you want to do so that it works for different inputs.

Comment: @KyleW My apologies, I've gone ahead and edited the first post. Hopefully this explanation is slightly better. I do not want each distinct value from List 1 matched with each distinct value from list 2. Instead I'm looking to match sets of symbols with their corresponding sets of values.

Comment: You are not interleaving the lists, you are "[Zipping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx)" the lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description it looks like the paired index matters, you are not trying to do a blind interleave. Here is how to do it with a GroupBy, I also put a 3 in the middle to demonstrate the ordering.

```
List<string> symbolList = new List<string>() { "1", "1", "3", "2", "2", "2" };
List<string> valueList = new List<string>() { "a1", "b1", "c3", "a2", "b2", "c2" };

var items = symbolList.Zip(valueList, (symbol, value) => new {symbol, value}) //pairs the like indexes with each other in to an anonymous type.
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.symbol, pair => pair.value) //Group together the values that share the same symbol
    .OrderBy(group => group.Key) //optional, only if you want the output to be 1,2,3
    .Select(group => String.Join("|", (new[] {group.Key}).Concat(group))); //Build up the "|" separated groups.
var result = String.Join(",", items); //Join together the groupings separated by ","

Console.WriteLine("result: " + result);
```

[<kbd>Click to Run</kbd>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LSWDXf)

It gives the result `result: 1|a1|b1,2|a2|b2|c2,3|c3`

Comment: This is exactly what I was attempting to do. Thank you for the example and the comments along with it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this out:

```
List<string> symbolList = new List<string>() { "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2" };
List<string> valueList = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c" };

string value =  string.Join(",", symbolList.Distinct().
                Select(f => String.Join("|", new List<string>() { f }
                .Concat(valueList.Distinct()))).ToList());

Console.WriteLine("result: " + value);
```

This code gives me `result: "1|a|b|c,2|a|b|c"`.

I hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

While not the answer to the original question, to strictly answer the title (which is what I came here looking for, just simply interleaving two lists):

```
var interleaved = list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => new[] { a, b }).SelectMany(p => p);
```

Example:

```
var l1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => (char) ('0' + i));
var l2 = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => (char) ('A' + i));

var interleaved = l1.Zip(l2, (a, b) => new[] { a, b }).SelectMany(p => p);
```